# Is there any way to define the datatype of value in state of hooks in functional component of react JS?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IC8HP.png):Firstly I added number and string in initial value of state of functional component of react using hooks.I found that Actually I can add numbers and strings together in state inital value.To know what would be the **typeOf** "final value" that I got after adding
numbers and string.I used console.log(typeOf(value).As you can see in the image I provided,The type of value is Undefined .So My question is can I define the type of value in state in react using hooks.So that only numbers or only strings could be changed or added in the state's value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have not correctly use typeof in your code you can use like this & it gives type string .

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0 + "hello");

  return (
    <div className="App">
         {console.log(typeof count)} // this is string
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Vyas Arpit answer; The reason you get undefined is because you're trying to access `value` outside of your function (component). If you put it inside the function, as Vyas showed, you will be able to access it.